# Router scene property for color header

Tags: react-native, react-router

good morning friends, some property to assign the title in the header a different color from the background color of the whole scene?
Something like the image attached to them.

[Header Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ayi6.jpg)

Comment: Are you using `NavagatorIOS`, `Navagator`, or something else?

Comment: I am using react-router-scene in conjunction with react-native-base tabs

Comment: I did it inline whit navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}